# android:RecyclerView set adapter

Tags: java, android

i am new to android,i want to create a list with recyclerview.
i have recycler view in my code and when i run it give me force close,
 and i know my problem is on set adapter -> RecyclerviewAdapter
because when i comment `recyclerview.setAdapter(mAdapte);`
 my app work fine

code of Market.class :

```
public class Market extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_market);


    // 1. get a reference to recyclerView
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RView);

    // this is data fro recycler view
    RecyclerViewDataObject [] items = {
            new RecyclerViewDataObject( "John Weak" , "Goalkeeper" , 99 , 990 ),
            new RecyclerViewDataObject( "Mamad Seyed" , "Backward" , 35 , 350 ),
            new RecyclerViewDataObject( "Mostafa Barimani" , "Forward" , 65 , 650 ),
            new RecyclerViewDataObject( "Reza Dahmarde" , "Backward" , 70 , 700 ),
            new RecyclerViewDataObject( "Sina Ashrafpour" , "Forward" , 85 , 850 )
    };

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    // 2. set layoutManger
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Market.this));
    // 3. create an adapter
    RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(items);
    // 4. set adapter
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    // 5. set item animator to DefaultAnimator
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());



}
```

}

code of RecyclerViewAdapter.class :

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {



private RecyclerViewDataObject [] items;


public RecyclerViewAdapter(RecyclerViewDataObject [] dataObjects){
    this.items = dataObjects;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_item, null);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.name.setText(items[position].getName());
    holder.post.setText(items[position].getPost());
    holder.rank.setText(items[position].getRank());
    holder.value.setText(items[position].getValue());

}



public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView name;
    public TextView rank;
    public TextView post;
    public TextView value;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {

        super(itemLayoutView);
        name = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name1);
        post = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.txt_post1);
        rank = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.txt_rank1);
        value = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.txt_value1);

    }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.length;
}
```

}

Logcat :

```
11-15 11:26:24.114 12175-12175/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.kikojas, PID: 12175
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kikojas/com.kikojas.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.cedarstudios.cedarmapssdk.MapView
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.cedarstudios.cedarmapssdk.MapView
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
       . . .
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq7In.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfrTM.png)

if any body  knows problem i am so interested to know that

Comment: can you post the stacktrace? You can find it in the logcat tab in Android Studio

Comment: i add my logcat at the end of my code

Comment: but i cant add all of them

Comment: because it consists of 262000 character

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kikojas/com.kikojas.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.cedarstudios.cedarmapssdk.MapView. This tells you where the error is. In your MainActivity xml file, probably activity_main.xml. Check for errors in your MapView. Please  add this xml for review

Comment: i have not any MainActivity...i post screenshot of my screen for you in my post

Comment: The stack trace you posted doesn't seem to indicate that the problem is with the `setAdapter`, but rather with `com.cedarstudios.cedarmapssdk.MapView`. This has some problem that crashes the app while inflating it. Unfortunately, the stack trace is not very clear about what the problem is. Could you post this class and the xml using it pls? thanks

Comment: witch class???@Fred

Comment: i think i find problem but i don't know how can i solve it...i put screen shot an the end of post.@Dr4ketheb4dass

Comment: i think i find problem but i don't know how can i solve it...i put screen shot an the end of post.@Fred

Comment: i think i find problem but i don't know how can i solve it...i put screen shot an the end of post.@JorgeGil

Comment: please add the `MapView`... all the code you've posted is irrelevant, b/c the error message reads `Error inflating class com.cedarstudios.cedarmapssdk.MapView`.

Comment: I am not using mapview at all @Martin Zeitler

Comment: @sajad what if I told you, that I don't think so? your `MainActivity`'s XML file certainly refers to it. or do you want to tell me, that the IDE is making up these error messages? therefore you have two options: a) remove it from the XML or b) provide us with it's Java code.

Comment: seems like the error is in `com.kikojas.app.MainActivity` file (of a different app? your activity is `com.example.bottombar.sample.Market` which indicates a different package at all... and the logcat screenshot shows "no debuggable process"... I think this crash stack trace is not related.